# NFS is freezing up when saving a file from video stream

Tags: nfs, fstab

I'm very lost here, i'm not really too experienced with NFS. I have multiple servers and 1 file server, the file server has a share using nfs that the other servers mount.

One of the servers uses openvidu and records live streams and then saves the stream to the file share.

Just lately when this happens the share seems to freeze up while this is happening, so if i ssh into one of the servers and try to ls /data (the share) it takes forever to list the files until the video saving is finished. It wasn't doing this until recently.

I have even switched to udp to try that but it still happens, my fstab is:

```
192.168.0.5:/data /data nfs nfsvers=4.2,soft,async,bg,nointr,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,udp,timeo=600 0 0
```

If you need any other info please let me know.

This could be more down to after the video is saved from openvidu that there is an endpoint that copies the zip file to another location and changes the permissions.

Comment: Did you check the hardware? RAID status? Anything of note in the logfiles?